# Dealing with unknown mutability in rust

Tags: rust, traits, mutability

I'm having trouble understanding when to use mutable references as opposed to immutable references in traits.

The following example for a Visitor implementation is taken from `Rust Design Patterns`:

```rust
mod visit {
    use ast::*;

    pub trait Visitor<T> {
        fn visit_name(&mut self, n: &Name) -> T;
        fn visit_stmt(&mut self, s: &Stmt) -> T;
        fn visit_expr(&mut self, e: &Expr) -> T;
    }
}
```

This pattern works well when modifying a node as one traverses the AST is not needed. But for some use-case, altering a node as you traverse might be a design choice worth making.

The solution from the book comes in form of the folder pattern:

```rust
mod fold {
    use ast::*;

    pub trait Folder {
        fn fold_name(&mut self, n: Box<Name>) -> Box<Name> { ... }
        fn fold_stmt(&mut self, s: Box<Stmt>) -> Box<Stmt> { ... }
        fn fold_expr(&mut self, e: Box<Expr>) -> Box<Expr> { ... }
    }
}
```

A similar thing can be achieved by simply making each AST node mutable.

However, having both solutions seems to be tedious and not maintainable. For a large AST with many different nodes, there is a lot of code duplication; one `Visitor` instance must be created for mutable nodes and one for non-mutable nodes. Is there a better way of achieving this 'optional mutability'?

Comment: Can't you just make the visitor take a `&mut T`? Then they can modify it in-place if they want, or simply write a new `T` into there otherwise

Comment: 'optional mutability' is not a thing, and the more you think about it the more you will understand why. If it were a thing, then you would have to implement it in a way that is compatible with both ways - which is immutably. So just use immutable references. But on the other hand, if you want to be able to use both cases when calling the function, then you would have to make them all mutable references, because those are compatible with both from that side. So it's basically impossible to combine those two versions.

Comment: Sure, this is possible but it feels like this falls into the same category as „why not make all iterators mutable?“. The main downside, however, is that this always requires read access to whatever the visitor operates on. Using multiple visitors simultaneously or using one visitor as part of another is then problematic.

Comment: I guess what I mean by ‚optional mutability‘ is rather ‚parameterized mutability‘ so that you can decide (using something like a type parameter or lifetime modifier) whether something should be mutable.

Comment: Be aware that `T` doesn't **have** to be a struct - you **can** implement traits for `&T` or `&mut T`. So in that sense, this kind of abstraction already exists.

Comment: Sure but the nodes themselves (Name, Stmt, Expr, …) is what I‘m worried about and they are structs. Are there any ways to abstract the mutability of the nodes?

Comment: @Schottky *'you can decide whether something should be mutable'* - Who is 'you' in that scenario? The caller or the callee? If the caller, how should a callee ever mutate itself if the caller might decide that the function now gets called immutably? If the callee decides, then what's the point? A `&mut self` would be fine, the callee doesn't **have** to modify anything. That's why I say it doesn't make sense to combine those two. I've been exactly at your point and it took me a while as well to understand this.

Comment: Could you maybe have an `ImmutableTrait` implementing immutable behavior, and `MutableTrait` implementing mutable behavior? Then the callee can at least choose when each behavior is introduced, but you'd still need a mutable reference when you wanted to mutate the data in any way short of interior mutability.

Comment: @Finomnis 'You' would be when implementing the trait, i.e. a concrete visitor (struct). This is when I know whether I want to change the underlying AST or not. Again, I don't have an issue with `&mut self` (this is almost always what I need) but rather with `&mut <Concrete Node>`. Do you then have any suggestion as to how to deal with the issue that, when reading I want to enable multiple read accesses but when writing only one thing (possibly a thread) should access the data structure at once?

Comment: @MeetTitan This is an option, yes. I'm thinking about a `MutableVisitor` trait that has functions like `fn visit_x(&mut self, &mut x: Node)` and a `Visitor` trait that has functions like `fn visit_x(&mut self, &x: Node)`. For a small example like the one above, this will probably work just fine but for larger examples with hundreds of Node variants that just becomes cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replicating the visitor is the correct thing to do. Rust has no way to abstract over the mutability of a reference, and there are many examples of doing that, even in std (e.g. slice iterators). If this is too much boilerplate, you can use a macro to help with it.